# Auto process CSS files

Tags: css, angular

I'm doing some UI dev in an Angular 2 (v4) project and currently have to re-run `ng serve...` to recompile the new styles, in order to get them to display in the app.

Is there a way to get the CSS styles to auto-compile in the same way adding html tags to a given component updates the app realtime?

Comment: are you saying you have some css file when you chaneg then don't recompile angular app while you runing ng serve ??

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It should automatically do that while serving.
Please provide more details.

Try disabling Use "safe write" in Settings of your IDE if that's a thing. It might cause that problem incidentally ( Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings in Jetbrains problems)

Change Angular CLI version?

Check out your .angular-cli.json could be something in there.

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to add css file to your project:

one way add the css file to assets folderthen import the file from style.css like this

```
@import url('./assets/theme.css');
```

in this case the file will be watch to change

another way from angular.json add the css file to styles array

```
   "styles": [
            "src/assets/theme.css",
             "src/styles.css"
    ],
```

notes that any change on **angular.json** file required to run angular server againg

{{ 'Happy Coding' }}